# Does WCF PerCall instances run in same process?

Tags: wcf

I need to run a legacy component that can be used only for one session per windows process.
I was advised by the support to use WCF concurrency/instancing to achieve parallelism.

The problem is that when I read about WCF concurrency/instancing, I can't understand how exactly WCF handle this under the hood. 
Does it create a separate windows process for every call if PerCall instances mode is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's just the WCF service instance that is recreated and used only once per call - the same hosting process is used for all calls.